# Directory exists check in metro app(not file)

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

```
Directory.Exists(imgFolder.Path);
```

alternate method in win8.1 store app,
im tried search online but i do get result for file exists only not to check folder exists

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Directory.Exists(imgFolder.Path); not supported in win8.1 store app, so im looking for alternate way to check directory exists or not.

Comment: I think the only way is to try it and catch the NoFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8.1 you need to do something like following.

The following method will check if files exists or not:

```
 public async Task<bool> isFilePresent(string fileName)
 {
 bool fileExists = true;
 Stream fileStream = null;
 StorageFile file = null;

 try
 {
 file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
 fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
 fileStream.Dispose();
 }
 catch (FileNotFoundException)
 {
 // If the file dosn't exits it throws an exception, make fileExists false in this case 
 fileExists = false;
 }
 finally
 {
 if (fileStream != null)
 {
 fileStream.Dispose();
 }
 }

 return fileExists;
 }
```

or:

```
public async Task<bool> isFilePresent(string fileName)
 {
 var item = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync(fileName);
 return item != null;
 }
```

From [Check If File Exists in Windows Phone 8 and Win RT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shashankyerramilli/archive/2014/02/17/check-if-a-file-exists-in-windows-phone-8-and-winrt-without-exception.aspx)

Comment: `StorageFolder.TryGetItemAsync()` is the way to go.